# Writing better functions

Tags: python

I've been using these two functions to write my CSV headers:

```py
def get_csv_headers():
    return ['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4']
    
def write_csv_headers():
    with open(csv_path, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=csv_headers)
        writer.writeheader()
    
csv_headers = get_csv_headers()
write_csv_headers()
```

However, I recently learned about `*args` and `**kwargs` (I'm a Python autodidact) and modified my code to:

```py
def write_csv_headers(*args):
    with open(csv_path, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=[*args])
        writer.writeheader()
    
csv_headers = write_csv_headers('col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4')
```

I'm trying to learn more about Pythonic syntax and apply Python best practices. Which one is better?

Comment: `[*args]` can just be `args`

Comment: Well, in this particular case, the second one is better, but not because you are using `*args`, because you are providing the headers as arguments to the function instead of relying on a global variable. `*args` isn't a great name either. Honestly, I would just do `write_csv_Headers(fieldnames)` and the just do `writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)` and pass a list to it, but if you prefer variadic arguments that is mostly a metter of preference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. You shouldn't hard-code the header names, it's good to use a function, like in the first version.

But you shouldn't use a global variable, you should pass the header names as an argument, as in the second version.

There's no need to use `*args` for this, it can be an ordinary parameter.

```
def get_csv_headers():
    return ['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4']

def write_csv_headers(path, headers):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()

csv_headers = get_csv_headers()
write_csv_headers(csv_path, csv_headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

*args and **kwargs are usually more for passing the args and kwargs along to another function down the road. In this case you're using the args directly. I think the pythonic way would be

```
headers = get_csv_headers()
write_csv_headers(headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

If function **get_csv_headers** returns a list I think it is better to first create a variable to get data from funtion and then pass it to second one as an arguments 
 code:

```
#let's assume that this func does some logic (like filtering) to get headers
def get_csv_headers():
    #filter code
    return ['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3', 'col 4']

def write_csv_headers(pathDir:str,headersList:list):
    with open(pathDir, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer=csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headersList)
        writer.writeheader()


filtered_headers=get_csv_headers()
write_csv_headers(pathDir='path', headerList=filterd_headers)
#or
write_csv_headers(pathDir='path', headerList=get_csv_headers())
```